# setText is not applicable

Tags: java, android, settext

I'm a beginner in Java. The question might be silly, but please help!
I've created tvlat and tvlong of the type TextView as global objects.

```
public TextView tvlat;
public TextView tvlong;
```

When I use them in the following code:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{   

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "Current location : " +
        "Lattitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +
        "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        tvlat.setText(“”+loc.getLatitude());
        tvlong.setText(“”+loc.getLongitude());
```

It says setText(char sequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments(double) for the code:

```
tvlat.setText(“”+loc.getLatitude());
tvlong.setText(“”+loc.getLongitude());
```

Obviously, it happens because tvlat and loc are of two different types. Can anyone suggest me the right way of casting the above statement or resolving the above problem?
Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote formatting is odd, it differs from `"`. You can try:

```
tvlat.setText(String.valueOf (loc.getLatitude()));
tvlong.setText(String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
tvlat.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
tvlong.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
```

to get String representation of Double

Comment: It still shows an error. loc is of type double. How can I convert double to string?

Comment: @Lg23 : see my edit answer . sorry actually getLatitude return Double then we will need to cast Double to String

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger : yes i mean get String representation of Double